# How to check for cursor position in PySimpleGUI for text input boxes?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am trying to make a calculator application as a beginner project.
I wish to have an input field and button inputs to add numbers, like 1,2,3.
[See application image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPJXB.png)
When I press the number buttons, it adds a number at the end.
But sometimes I want to add a number in another position.
Is there a way to detect where the typing cursor is so that I can add it for where the user's cursor is?
This will make it more intuitive to use, but I don't know how.

For example, if the user types in the number, 10358, and their cursor is hovering between 3 and 5, like
103|58,
I want it to add the next number behind 3, as it is where the cursor is.

Instead, my code adds it to the end.
So if the user presses the button 3, it becomes 103583 instead of 103358

Here is the full source code.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
current_result = ""
past_result = ""
def calc(expression):
    try:
        return eval(expression)
    except:
        return 0
layout = [[sg.Input('My Calculator App. Type or use key input',key='-RESULT-')],
          [sg.Text("Your result is stored here",key='-OLDRESULT-')],
          [sg.B("1",key="-1-"),sg.B("2",key='-2-'),sg.B('3',key='-3-')],
          [sg.B("=",key="-EXECUTE-")]]      

window = sg.Window('Calculator Application', layout)    

while True:
    
    event, values = window.read()    
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == "Exit":
        break
    for i in range(0,10):
        if event == "-{}-".format(i):
            current_result += str(i)
            window['-RESULT-'].update(current_result)
    if event == "-EXECUTE-":
        current_result = values['-RESULT-']
        if calc(current_result) != 0:
            current_result = str(calc(current_result))
            window['-OLDRESULT-'].update(current_result)
        else:
            window['-OLDRESULT-'].update("Invalid Syntax")
window.close()
```

I tried to make a window, with buttons for numerical input.
It adds it to the back, not where the user's typing cursor is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tkinter code required here, get the icursor position by `element.widget.index(sg.tk.INSERT)`.

```py
...
window = sg.Window('Calculator Application', layout, finalize=True)
entry = window['-RESULT-'].widget
...
    elif event in ('-1-', '-2-', '-3-'):
        number = event[1]
        index = entry.index(sg.tk.INSERT)
        current_result = current_result[:index] + number + current_result[index:]
        window['-RESULT-'].update(current_result)
        entry.icursor(index + 1)
```